# Deriving tilex and tiley to retrieve link data

Tags: here-api

I'm trying to retrieve link attributes but the response contains no data.

I'm using R but the area of interest is an area just West of London at:

latitude = 51.561
longitude = -0.4958

Using these lats and longs with the tilex and y formulas in the HERE API documention gives:

```
lat <- 51.561
long <- -0.4958
level <- 10

#tilex
tilex <- floor(long+180/(180/2^level))

#tiley
tiley <-floor(lat+90/(180/2^level))
```

The following is the call to the API.

```
resource <- "tile"

base_url <- paste0("https://pde.api.here.com/1/", resource, ".json?")

layer <- 'LINK_ATTRIBUTE_FC2'

level <- '10'

query <- list(app_id = app_id, 
              app_code = app_code, 
              region="WEU", 
              layer = layer,
              level = level,
              tilex = tileX,
              tiley = tiley)

request <- GET(url = base_url, query = query, verbose(), add_headers(headers = c('Accept-Encoding' = "gzip, deflate")))

response <- content(request, as = "text", encoding = "utf-8")

fromJSON(response, simplifyDataFrame = TRUE)
```

This returns an empty list. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

you have an empty list because Latitude:-51.561 longitude: -0.4958 is east of Falkland islands, in the south of the Atlantic ocean.

try 51.561, -0.4958 and you'll get 619 rows in the answer.

Comment: Latitude is set to positive 51.561. Apols for typo in the description - have edited. In code positive 51.561 is being assigned to the object `lat` by `<-`.

Comment: Do you have  tileX: 1021, tileY: 805 ?
URL should be something like https://pde.api.here.com/1/tile.json?app_id=XXXXX&app_code=YYYY&meta=1&layer=LINK_ATTRIBUTE_FC2&level=10&tilex=1021&tiley=805

Comment: Thanks for providing the reference values. I've identified it was an issue with evaluation of the parentheses in deriving tilex-tiley. Correct srtucture is `tilex <- floor((long+180)/(180/2^level))`